# gem directory not found(Ruby)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am new in Ruby.This is my first post in this forum and hoping my problem will get resolved.

```
[root@server ~]# which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
[root@server ~]# which gem
/usr/bin/which: no gem in 
(/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/nz/bin:)
[root@smqa-devdb3 ~]# gem list
bash: gem: command not found
[root@server ~]# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25) [x86_64-linux]
```

How I can install gems? I want to install gems. I am able to run all ruby scripts like test.rb.

Please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange you don't have it shipped with ruby. However, you can always look at http://rubygems.org/, especially http://rubygems.org/pages/download

Answer (score 0):

You need to go [here](http://rubygems.org/pages/download) and download either the TGZ or ZIP version, unarchive and install it with:

```
ruby setup.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Start at the [Installing RubyGems](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3) page.  You should find enough info there to install it.  Without knowing more about your Linux distro it's not possible to give more specific answers.